# How to use ColSums in R with condition

Tags: r, sum

I want to sum over columns 2 to 4 and columns 7 to 51 in my data for one municipality coded by the variable cat_b. I want to create a new row with these totals.

For now, I have just used colsums for the two sets of variables but since they are separate commands, they will create two rows rather than one which is what I want

In this dataset Budget_panel is the working directory

```
c1<- colSums(Budget_panel[,1:4])
c2<- colSums(Budget_panel[,7:51])
```

Is there a concise way to do this?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example along with expected output?

Comment: You can join multiple sequences together - `c(1:4,7:51)` - is that all you want?

Comment: `colSums(Budget_panel[,c(7:51, 7:51)])` like what @thelatemail said.

Answer (score 0):

An option is `summarise_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
Budget_panel %>%
      summarise_at(c(1:4, 7:51), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I may have not been that clear but i want a new row with the sums for these specific columns and I also want the condition 'if cat_b=="TSH1"'

Comment: Try `Budget_panel %>%
      summarise_at(c(1:4, 7:51), list(~ sum(.[cat_b == "TSH1"], na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: How do I use the summarise_at command? Is there any particular library for it?

Comment: @NM I diddn't get your question.  The function is from `library(dplyr)` which gets loaded when you load `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it again and now I get this error message: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: @NM  It works fine for me `set.seed(24); Budget_panel <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10 * 100), 10, 100))`